# How to prevent or block closing a WinForms window?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I prevent window closing by showing a `MessageBox`? (Technology:`WinForms` with `C#`)

When the close event occurs I want the following code to be run:

```
private void addFile_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e ) {
    var closeMsg = MessageBox.Show( "Do you really want to close?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question );

    if (closeMsg == DialogResult.Yes) {
        //close addFile form
    } else {
        //ignore closing event
    }
}
```

Comment: Prevent your winform closing or the messagebox?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    var window = MessageBox.Show(
        "Close the window?", 
        "Are you sure?", 
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

    e.Cancel = (window == DialogResult.No);
}
```

Answer (score 34):

Catch FormClosing event and set `e.Cancel = true`

```
private void AdminFrame_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    var res = MessageBox.Show(this, "You really want to quit?", "Exit",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2);
    if (res != DialogResult.Yes)
    {
      e.Cancel = true;
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. You could, if you really wanted, inline the call to MessageBox.Show(), but this is exactly what the OP needs to do.

Comment: In the case he wants to ask the user "You have unsaved data! Do you want to save before exiting?" he will have 3 outcomes, yes, no and cancel. So for future its propably good to have res at hand for further processing.

Answer (score 9):

A special twist might be to always prevent just the user closing the form:

```
private void Frm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing); 
    // disable user closing the form, but no one else
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Within your `OnFormClosing` event you can show the dialog and `if` answer is false (to not show) then set the `Cancel` property of the `EventArgs` to `true`.

Answer (score 3):

For prevent or block the form closing in particular situation you can use this strategy:

```
private void MyForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{

    if (FLAG_CONDITION == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("To exit save the change!!");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Straight from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing):

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
   // Determine if text has changed in the textbox by comparing to original text. 
   if (textBox1.Text != strMyOriginalText)
   {
      // Display a MsgBox asking the user to save changes or abort. 
      if(MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save changes to your text?", "My Application",
         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) ==  DialogResult.Yes)
      {
         // Cancel the Closing event from closing the form.
         e.Cancel = true;
         // Call method to save file...
      }
   }
}
```

In your case you don't need to do anything to explicitly close the form.  Unless you cancel it it will close automatically, so your code would be:

```
private void addFile_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e ) {
    var closeMsg = MessageBox.Show( "Do you really want to close?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question );

    if (closeMsg == DialogResult.Yes) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run any code you want when closing the form then, hide the form instead of closing it to prevent it from being disposed

```
yourFormName.FormClosing += (s, e) =>
{
   // any code you want
   yourFormName.Hide(); // this hides the form
   e.Cancel = true;  // this cancels the close event, you can put any boolean exprission 
};
```