# How do you let only authorized user have access to exit application or close specific Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to only allow user whose role is "Admin" to exit application.I use following code for this purpose but after delivering message application is terminating.

```
private void Login_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Login.role != "Admin")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are not authorized to Exit Application.");
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

i also used this on FormClosing event.but not get proper functioning. i am using c# windows application.

Comment: how about `this.close()` ?

Comment: I am not getting any error on application.exit() but i need to stop unauthorized person to terminate.

Comment: But what is wrong with `FromClosing` ?

Comment: my requirement is besides admin no one can close this form.after checking condition compiler run this code automatically to dispose  protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

Comment: The FormClosed event occurs after the form has been closed by the user or by the Close method or the Exit method of the Application class. To prevent a form from closing, handle the FormClosing event and set the Cancel property of the CancelEventArgs passed to your event handler to true. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent closing a WinForms window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409529/prevent-closing-a-winforms-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add:

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

to the `if (Login.role != "Admin")` section.

You'll need to add this to the `FormClosing` event handler, rather than the `FormClosed` event handler though.

Answer (score 4):

Use the FormClosing event and try the following code:

```
private void Login_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (Login.role != "Admin")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are not authorized to Exit Application.");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The FormClosed event is too late. Use the FormClosing event! There you have `e.Cancel`, which helps you to cancel the closing process.

Answer (score 1):

Add `FormClosing` event handler and put the following code inside it:

```
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = Login.role != "Admin";
    }
```