# WinForms - Alert When User Leaves Page Without Saving

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a Windows Forms application for servicing equipment out in the field. We have a section of the application that contains configuration input fields.

What I want to do is create an alert for the user if they leave a page without saving their changes. Is there a way to do this in WinForms?

We handle navigation by controlling the visibility of elements on a given screen. Clicking a button triggers an event that changes the visibility of everything on the current page to "false" while setting the new screen to "true"

Comment: How do you "leave" a "page" in WinForms?

Comment: [How to prevent or block closing a WinForms window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409529/how-to-prevent-or-block-closing-a-winforms-window)

Comment: Good point. I could tie an event to clicking on any one of the main menu buttons. That's what I was thinking.

Comment: It all depends on how your application's layout works, and how you navigate between "pages", which aren't a built-in concept in WinForms.

Comment: No it's not about the WinForms window.... We do our navigation by controlling visibility of elements on the page. Different than the one you posted @CodeCaster