# how to program the alt+tab close button in a c#.net winforms application

Tags: c#, .net

I have this winform app that tracks battery life, if I close the app during an "alt+tab" (like in the pic below) it closes the app completely.

[image]

I want to program the close button (if this is possible) to minimize the app to the system tray instead of closing it completely.

I have not seen any similar solutions for this, all I see is disabling the alt+tab on a winforms app.

I want to do this because if I close the app the battery percentage wont be monitored anymore, I just want to know if this is possible though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent or block closing a WinForms window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409529/how-to-prevent-or-block-closing-a-winforms-window)

Comment: Use the `FormClosing` event as shown in the linked question and set `e.Cancel` to true after checking any validation logic you need. Make sure not to prevent closing if `e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown` so that your program doesn't interrupt the shutdown process.

Comment: @41686d6564 oh yeah, I did not think of the form closing event. Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to minimize to system tray first add NotifyIcon on your form from Toolbox.
And then add this code accordingly.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu notifyMenu;
private System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem notifyMenuItemClose;
public static bool close = false;

public ApplicationWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void ApplicationWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.notifyMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
    this.notifyMenuItemClose = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
    this.notifyMenu.MenuItems.AddRange( new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem[] { this.notifyMenuItemClose });
    this.notifyMenuItemClose.Index = 0;
    this.notifyMenuItemClose.Text = "Exit";
    this.notifyMenuItemClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyMenuItemClose_Click);
    this.notifyAppIcon.ContextMenu = this.notifyMenu;

}

private void notifyMenuItemClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    close = true;
    this.Close();
}

private void ApplicationWindow_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (close)
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private void notifyAppIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button==MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        this.Show();
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just add  these lines of code on my formclosing: this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            e.Cancel = true;
            NotifyIcon.Visible = true;

is this okay?

Comment: I dont fully understand what that e.Cancel means though, can you enlighten me?

Comment: If you hover over your e.Cancel VS promts explanation.It says "Gets or sets a value indicating wether the event should be canceled" which means it cancel default behavior of form close event which is well... closing the form.

Comment: If you want to differ whether your close form was triggered by clicking X or from something else like alt+tab custom behavior you can use simple bool variable called close like in example I posted.